# How can I make CSS calc function work in IE9 with negative numbers?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

I have tried the following:

```
-ms-transform: translateY(calc(-100% - 70px));

-ms-transform: translateY(calc(- 100% - 70px));

-ms-transform: translateY(calc(0 - 100% - 70px));

-ms-transform: translateY(calc(0px - 70px - 100%));
```

None of this is picked up by IE9. Any idea how to get this to work in IE9? Works in Chrome and other modern browsers.

Comment: If you feel the need to vote down my question, can you please explain why?

Comment: Could you maybe try position top or bottom instead of transform for a workaround?

Comment: Thanks, might try that as a fallback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**caniuse**](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc) reports that:

> IE10 and IE11 don't support using calc() inside a transform.

View the [official bug report at MS IE trac](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/814380/) (seems to be working on Edge tho)

Comment: Thanks, that explains things. Also your tip with top bottom will provide a nice potential fallback!